# Topological invariant on isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Does there exist a topological invariant (like Euler Characteristic) that is invariant to isomorphism on graphs? In other words, this topological invariant should be equal up to isomorphism on graph or simplicial complexes derived from graphs, like clique complexes.

Comment: You named one --- the Euler characteristic.  Now what is the question?

Comment: Did not realize that the Euler Characteristic is invariant to isomorphism on graphs.

Comment: just to quickly mention the following: the homotopy-invariant topological things are really only sensitive to the number of cycles in a graph, since every graph is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of circles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at graphs as special cases of simplicial complexes (that is, as a full subcategory of the category of simplicial complexes), then every invariant on simplicial complexes is an invariant on graphs. This incluces homology, homotopy, cohomology, etc.